# How to convert a json to a html using a Groovy script

Tags: html, json, jenkins, groovy

As the title suggests, i'm trying to convert a json to a html using Groovy. I know how to do this in python, but since this code is running in jenkins,i need to find a way to the same using Groovy.

**This json :**

```
[
{
    "kubernetes.pod.name": "sds-endpoints-6-hn0fe2l",
    "container.id": "d19e001824978",
    "memory.used.percent": 102,
    "cpu.used.percent": 7,
    "memory.bytes.used (mB)": 2067,
    "cpu.cores.used (millicores)": 9,
    "endTime": "2018-07-04T02:00:00+0000"
},
{
    "kubernetes.pod.name": "product-service-endpoints-4-da1w",
    "container.id": "4dd6447f5e14",
    "memory.used.percent": 84,
    "cpu.used.percent": 7,
    "memory.bytes.used (mB)": 1698,
    "cpu.cores.used (millicores)": 8,
    "endTime": "2018-07-04T02:00:00+0000"}
]
```

**To this html :**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
<thead><tr><th title="Field #1">kubernetes.pod.name</th>
<th title="Field #2">container.id</th>
<th title="Field #3">memory.used.percent</th>
<th title="Field #4">cpu.used.percent</th>
<th title="Field #5">memory.bytes.used (mB)</th>
<th title="Field #6">cpu.cores.used (millicores)</th>
<th title="Field #7">endTime</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr>
<td>sds-endpoints-6-hn0fe2l</td>
<td>d19e001824978</td>
<td align="right">102</td>
<td align="right">7</td>
<td align="right">2067</td>
<td align="right">9</td>
<td>2018-07-04T02:00:00+0000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>product-service-endpoints-4-da1w</td>
<td>4dd6447f5e14</td>
<td align="right">84</td>
<td align="right">7</td>
<td align="right">1698</td>
<td align="right">8</td>
<td>2018-07-04T02:00:00+0000</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

**How in python (relevant?) :**

```
from json2html import *

print json2html.convert(json = json_data)    

with open("jsonREPORT.html", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(json2html.convert(json = json_data), write_file ,sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

***ANY suggestion how in Groovy?***

Comment: Why not use the Python plugin? In any case, if you want to do it in Groovy, learn you a Groovy for great good--it's pretty easy, but AFAIK the Python you show won't create the HTML you want anyway, so you'd still need to output the headers, then iterate the rows, then close everything up anyway. I'd just search for processing JSON in Groovy, and there are multiple ways to create HTML, all of which are pretty easy.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for taking time to respond, the python plugin is missing some dependency , however, you're right about processing json. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you reading this and youre wondering the same, i've found a way.**

```
def inputFile = new File("D:\\Github\\rest-api testing\\hm\\out.json")
def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)


def writer = new StringWriter()  // html is written here by markup builder
def markup = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)  // the builder

// MAKE OF HTML
markup.html{
markup.table(class:"table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed") {
markup.thead{
markup.tr {
    markup.th(title:"Field #1", "kubernetes.pod.name")
    markup.th(title:"Field #2", "container.id")
    markup.th(title:"Field #3", "memory.used.percent")
    markup.th(title:"Field #4", "cpu.used.percent")
    markup.th(title:"Field #5", "memory.bytes.used (mB)")
    markup.th(title:"Field #6", "cpu.cores.used (millicores)")
    markup.th(title:"Field #7", "endTime")
} // tr
} // thead
markup.tbody{
markup.tr{ for (def data : InputJSON.data) {
    markup.tr{
        markup.td(align:"right",data.d[0])
        markup.td(align:"right",data.d[1])
        markup.td(align:"right",Math.round((data.d[2]) * 100))
        markup.td(align:"right",Math.round((data.d[3]) * 100))
        markup.td(align:"right",Math.round((data.d[4]) * 0.000001))
        markup.td(align:"right",Math.round(((data.d[5]) * 1000)))
        markup.td(align:"right",new Date(((long) InputJSON.end) * 1000))
    } // foreach
} // td
} // tr
} //tbody
} // table
}

println writer.toString()
```

Answer (score 4):

test.json

```json
[
    {"f1":12345, "f2":"abcdfg"},
    {"f1":67890, "f2":"qwerty"}
]
```

test.gsp

```jsp
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>f1</td>
        <td>f2</td>
    </tr>
    <% for(r in data) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= r.f1 %></td>
        <td><%= r.f2 %></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

groovy code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

new File("/test.html").withWriter("UTF-8"){writer->
    new SimpleTemplateEngine()
        .createTemplate( new File("/test.gsp") )
        .make( data:new JsonSlurper().parse(new File("/test.json")) )
        .writeTo( writer )
}
```